# How to call custom js script on click some dom element in odoo v9?

Tags: javascript, odoo-9

Im build extension for one of the standart openerp modules, and i stuck on problem. I have js code which do ajax request and back data which i needed to some fields it works but it is uncomfortably to always reload page to get new data, because all standart methods like call some tag with .click function doesnt work, i supose it override by standart odoo methods. How can i call my js for field like that . Please help me solve my problem.

```
<page string="Some data" id="some_id">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/web/static/src/js/test.js"></script>
<label string="Get data" id="test11" />



$('#some_id').click(function(){
$.ajax({some ajax stuff})
});
```